# Is there any way to combine data with power?

Tags: power, ttl

Imagine I have a standard TTL data signal and want to transmit that data along the same wire that provides power for the receiving device. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you add more detail, please? What data rate do you need to support, and over what distance?

Comment: Does it have to be *TTL* data, or do you just need digital data and power to both be available to a remote device, over a single pair of wires?

Comment: And yet more detail: how much power, and what voltages are acceptable (DC-DC converted at both ends acceptable?). For the Data: is it continuous or message-like (could it be transformer-coupled?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It possible, there are bus architectures that already do this such as [One wire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Wire) and maybe [HART protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highway_Addressable_Remote_Transducer_Protocol)(only if you can power up from the 4-20mA loop)

Comment: And on a higher voltage scale, there is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerline_communication

Comment: Indeed! And as a matter of fact the arduino ecosystem has the mamba shield for such type of communication

Comment: And various protocols for digital model railroads, e.g. DCC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Command_Control .